# Use vba Change the dates in MS-Word ContentControl DatePicker

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a MS-Word form that contain some Date Pickers, I need to create vba that changes the dates to the next week (date+7days), can anyone help me please?

I tried this but it didn't work

```
Dim PODate As Date
Dim strDate As String
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim ccs As Word.ContentControl
Set doc = ActiveDocument
Set ccs = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Date1").Item(1)
strDate = ccs.Range.Text
PODate = CDate(strDate)
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Date1"
Selection.TypeText Text:=Format(PODate + 7, "mm/dd/yyyy")
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is pretty basic.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/use-vba-change-the-dates-in-ms-word-contentcontrol/8f7878f5-f491-41fa-8f53-bf9c04b4fd5d. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim strDate As String
With ActiveDocument
  strDate = .SelectContentControlsByTag("Date1").Item(1).Range.Text
  .Bookmarks("Date1").Range.Text = Format(DateAdd("d", 7, strDate), "mm/dd/yyyy")
End With
```

or even:

```
With ActiveDocument
  .Bookmarks("Date1").Range.Text = Format(DateAdd("d", 7, .SelectContentControlsByTag("Date1").Item(1).Range.Text), "mm/dd/yyyy")
End With
```